# Permission issues with apex classes

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

We have few apex classes which has @InvocableMethod and are used inside screen flows on production. These apex classes is not given access in profile/permission set. We have custom profile 'Platform user' which is assign to the user who are using these screen flows.

Past few months we have been observing apex classes with @InvocableMethod having permission issues. We have same setup with user and profile in place on QA but we do not get those permission errors. When we add the apex class access to 'Platform user' profile the issue gets resolved.

I am having trouble understanding why this issue only occurring on production but not on the QA org. Does anyone have any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any perm sets in use, and do you have any system permissions set on QA that might mean it works there?

Comment: Yes we do have permission sets and we are giving field level access to the fields which are used in apex class, but not giving affected apex class access anywhere and the permission sets and System permissions on QA and prod is same around flow and apex class setting

Answer (score 2):

If a flow invokes Apex, the running user must have the corresponding Apex class security set in their user profile or permission set.

Refer the [Require User Access to Apex Classes Invoked by Flow (Release Update, Retired)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_release_update_require_user_access_to_apex_classes_invoked_by_flow.htm&type=5&release=240)

May be in your production org `Require User Access to Apex Classes Invoked by Flow` permission is activated that is the reason you were getting apex class access issues.

Follow the below steps to deactivate that feature in production.

> From Setup, enter Critical Updates in the Quick Find box. Then select
> Critical Updates. For Require User Access to Apex Classes Invoked by
> Flow, click Deactivate.

This update disables the requirement for a user running a flow to have explicit access to Apex classes invoked by that flow. This update was first made available in Summer ’20 and was scheduled to be enforced in Spring ’23, but we postponed the enforcement date to Summer ’23.

Refer the [Disable Rules for Enforcing Explicit Access to Apex Classes (Release Update)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_release_update_disable_apex_access_controls.htm&type=5&release=240)